# How to calculate area of a double-line road network in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, area, road

I have a line vector file that displays a road network. Most roads consist of a double-line indicating the sides of the road (hence the width of individual segments), but some roads are indicated by a single line. Furthermore, many segments are open shapes, so a line to polygon conversion does not "fill in" the paved roadway correctly, but ends up creating random polygons across multiple road segments.

I'd like to calculate the total area of the paved surface of the roads but am unsure how to do this. If I were to calculate the length of the lines and then use an average width to approximate area, the length would be incorrect because most roads are represented by two lines - but some roads only have one line - so I can't simply divide the total length by two. There is also a lot of variability in the width of the roads.

Is there a way either to convert the lines to polygons - but respecting the "pavement" of the roads? Or another method altogether? I attached a screenshot to illustrate (the buildings are a separate polygon layer).

[image]

Comment: Oh, nice. This is a lot of manual work if you really want to do it correct.

Comment: I originally tried to do a land use classification from Sentinel2 data, but there were a lot of incorrectly classified pixels because the urban areas are so variable. I don't have a lot of experience with classification though so I thought the vector files might be easier.

Comment: The data is from the Carta Technica Regionale in Italy (link below). The road layers are in the "05_VIABILITA'" zip file. The line layers are the shapefiles that start with "05L_"etc. http://dati.lazio.it/catalog/it/dataset/carta-tecnica-regionale-2002-2003-5k-roma/resource/ee089059-bdec-499c-a91c-a3f2a71f32ce?fbclid=IwAR22xpmHng4PD66vNe_htHnx7_er95ghxwORwWYqNkrroMwq9aH2IE0EZpM

Comment: There is a processing tool, Split with Lines (processing toolbox -> Vector Overlay -> Split with Lines) which should help you but after having testing the tool with you sample data, it does not yield good results.  See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Pwmam5c7KE&t=160s&ab_channel=StevenBernard

Comment: Might be useful to split the road segments into two categories based on their number of lines. 1. single line roads need a set buffer distance. 2. double lined roads need a different approach. Can the single lined roads be identified through the attribute table? Interesting question!

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestions. In the end, I located another set of vector files that included the roads as polygons, so I didn't need to create this myself (thankfully!).

Comment: That's great to hear! I'd be honest, I am still curious though